# Show $Px \perp (x-Px)$ and prove $||P|| \leq 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and linear operator $P:H \rightarrow H$ satisfy $\langle Px,y\rangle = \langle x,Py\rangle$ for all $x,y \in H$ and $P^2=P$.

(a) Show that $Px \perp (x-Px)$ for every $x \in H$.

(b) Use (a) and the Phythagoras' theorem to prove $||P|| \le 1$

---

(a) If $Px \perp (x-Px)$, then $\langle Px,x-Px\rangle = 0$, so we can show this.

By using $\langle Px,y\rangle = \langle x,Py\rangle$, we have $\langle Px,x-Px\rangle = \langle x,Px-P^2x\rangle = \langle x,Px-Px\rangle = \langle x,0\rangle$ but don't know what to do after this.

(b) I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you can prove from the inner product axioms that $\langle x,0 \rangle = 0$.

In the second case, suppose $x$ is unit, write $x=Px+(x-Px)$, then expand $\| x \|^2$ using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: so my (a) is pretty much correct right? Since by the axioms, <x,0>=0?

Comment: @snowman Yep, it's fine.

Comment: For (b): $||x||^2=||Px+(x-Px)||^2 \leq ||Px||^2 +||x-Px||^2$, I don't know how to evaluate these norms. We are supposed to use the definition of norm of linear operators right? But I have it for stuff like $||P||$ only and not $||Px||$...

Comment: @snowman $\| P \| = \sup_{\| x \|=1} \| Px \|$. So it is enough to show $\| Px \| \leq 1$ whenever $x$ is unit.

Comment: do you mind writing it all down for me with some explanation please? Its my first time dealing with this stuff so I am a bit dumb with it...

Comment: @snowman I would go further except you are already almost there: the only thing you need is to notice that $\| Px \|^2=1-\| x-Px \|^2 \leq 1$...

Comment: I'm late to the party, but @snowman, you have to use $||x||^2 = ||Px||^2 + ||x -Px||^2$ by the parallelogram law (as $Px$ and $x-Px$ are orthogonal by hypothesis). What I'm saying is that the inequality is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

For (b) note that by Pythagoras:
$$ \def\n#1{\left\|#1\right\|}
\n{x}^2 = \n{Px}^2 + \n{x-Px}^2 \ge \n{Px}^2 $$
Hence, 
$$ \n{Px} \le \n x $$
for all $x$, that is $\n P \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to crack (b). Use Cauchy-Schwarz to write
$$||Px||^2 = \langle Px, Px \rangle = \langle x, P^2 x\rangle = \langle x, Px \rangle \leq ||x|| \cdot ||Px||.$$

Now if $||Px|| = 0$ then $||Px|| \leq ||x||$ obviously. So assume otherwise and cancel out $||Px||$ to get that for all $x$ that $||Px|| \leq ||x||$.